# close div with animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I press the X, I able to open the searchbox with animation. I also able to close the searchbox when I click on the X inside the searchbox but without animation. I tried to change the animation-name in Javascript, but it has no effect. Anyone can help me with the code, if possible I try not to use jQuery. Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style type="text/css">
@keyframes open {
    0% {
        width: 0;
    }
    100% {
        width: 100%;
      }
}

#searchbox {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  float: right;
  animation-name: open;
}

#searchbox img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}

#searchbox input {
  max-width: 185px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color:white;
  border: none;
  outline:none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 15%;
  color: black;
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openSearchBox() {
  var searchbox=document.getElementById("searchbox");
  searchbox.style.display = "block";
  searchbox.style.width = "100%";
}

function closeSearchBox() {
  var searchbox=document.getElementById("searchbox");
  searchbox.style.display = "none";
  searchbox.style.width = "0";

}
</script>
<h1 onclick="openSearchBox()">X</h1>
<div id="searchbox">
      <img onclick="closeSearchBox()" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/70/70460.svg">
      <form>
        <input type="text">
      </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use two `CSS @keyframes Rule`. One for `opening` and other for `closing` the element. Also remove the `width`, `display` and `animation-name` from `#searchbox` style list.

**Do this:**

```js
function openSearchBox() {
  var searchbox = document.getElementById( 'searchbox' );
  searchbox.style.animationName = 'open';
  searchbox.style.width = '100%'
}

function closeSearchBox() {
  var searchbox = document.getElementById( 'searchbox' );
  searchbox.style.animationName = 'close';
  searchbox.style.width = '0'
}
```

```css
@keyframes open {
  0% { width: 0 }
  100% { width: 100% }
}
@keyframes close {
  0% { width: 100% }
  100% { width: 0 }
}
h1 {
  cursor: pointer
}
#searchbox {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  float: right
}
#searchbox img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%)
}
#searchbox input {
  max-width: 185px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: white;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 15%;
  color: black;
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<h1 onclick="openSearchBox()">X</h1>
<div id="searchbox">
  <img onclick="closeSearchBox()" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/70/70460.svg">
  <form>
    <input type="text">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use transition:width 1s; in #searchbox 's css

```
#searchbox {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);     
  overflow: hidden;
  /* animation-duration: 1s;*/
  float: right;
  /*animation-name: open;*/
   transition:width 1s;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are animating a element that has a `display: none` property. This property can't be animated in css. A solution can be to remove the display none property and find another solution like: `overflow: hidden` and `width: 0`.

I also recommend doing style changes in css only and not in JavaScript, this will speed up your website. By just adding a simple class you have more controll in your css and your JavaScript files.